# Ubuntu 16.04 stuck at '/dev/sda2: clean' after purging nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, xubuntu

History :

> To solve a black-screen-after-login problem I added `nomodeset` to the grub file and successfully logged in.
>
> But the resolution wasn't alright. So I went ahead and switched to a Nvidia driver from the nouveau option in 'additional drivers'.
>
> After rebooting I get was getting logged out right after logging in. I couldn't even get into guest account. So I went to tty1 and purged nvidia-current drivers. I also reinstalled X server.
>
> Now my system gets stuck on the boot at `/dev/sda2: clean`

What should I do now?
I installed a fresh Ubuntu few days back just to get rid of this problem. It has something to do with nvidia drivers I'm sure. I think switching to nouveau drivers temporarily can solve this stuck boot. Just a thought.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Please [edit] and post your graphics card so we can check which Nvidia drivers version is correct. The `nvidia-current` most likely isn't and that was the starting point of your problems. Can you still open tty?

Comment: yes I can open tty and my graphics card is Nvidia GT 635M and it all started when I got a black screen after login problem.

Comment: Then purge all nvidia "attempts" with `sudo apt purge nvidia*". Now you can install the correct driver version, any 367 or higher (never `nvidia-current`), i.e., `sudo apt install nvidia-367` (replace 367 with a newer and available version if you want).

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm